# Unit Testing with DbContext mock through Service Layer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, nunit, dbcontext

I'm a beginner at writing unit tests and I have a test I'm trying to get working. I'll start of by explaining what I'm trying to test.

I'm trying to test a method which saves messages in a Mvc 4 project. The method is called `SaveMessage` and is shown below.

```
namespace ChatProj.Service_Layer
{
    public class UserService : IUserService
    {
        public MessageContext messageContext = new MessageContext();

        public UserService()
        {
            _messageRepository = new MessageRepository(messageContext);
        }

        private  IMessageRepository _messageRepository;

    ->  public void SaveMessage(Message message)
        {
             messageContext.Messages.Add(message);
            _messageRepository.Save();
        }
```

The `_messageRepository.Save` in the `SaveMessage` method is implemented in my DAL layer `MessageRepository` and looks like this:

```
public void Save()
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

This way of saving will seem a bit overcomplicated, but I structured the project this way because I didn't want the service layer (`IUserService` & `UserService`) to handle operations that could & should (i think) be handled by the Data Access Layer (`IMessageRepository` & `MessageRepository`).

Now comes the tricky part. I've been trying to understand how I could unit test this. This is my try:

```
namespace ChatProj.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    class MessageRepositoryTests
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {

        }

        [Test]
    public void SaveMessage_SaveWorking_VerifyUse()
    {
        //Arrange
        var userServiceMock = new Mock<UserService>();
        var message = new Message { MessageID = 0, Name = "Erland", MessageString = "Nunit Test", MessageDate = DateTime.Now };
        var repositoryMock = new Mock<IMessageRepository>();
        var contextMock = new Mock<MessageContext>();
        MessageRepository messageRepository = new MessageRepository(contextMock.Object);
        UserService userService = new UserService();

        //Act
        userService.SaveMessage(message);

        //Assert
        repositoryMock.Verify(m => m.Save());
        userServiceMock.Verify(m => m.SaveMessage(message));
    }
}
```

I get this error: [Imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9qxj.jpg) , and I'm not quite sure how to solve it. I've tried looking at several other SO posts but I fail to make the test work.

So I'm wondering, how do I practically get my Unit Test to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should setup your `MessageContext` properties to return fake data and don't make real Db call with SaveChanges method.
Right now it still tries to access a real DB.

But you can setup only virtual properties or if it will be an inteface.

So the best solution is to extract an interface from your `MessageContext` and inject it into repository. Then you can easily mock your `IMessageContext` interface and force it to return appropriate in-memory data.

Comment: I've created a simple interface for my MessageContext which looks like this: [IMessageContext](http://imgur.com/WTBebN3,oP7TyLe)

How do I inject it into the repository, and how do I force it to return appropritate in-memory data? I'm not sure how injecting works, should I add it in my `MessageRepository` constructor?: [MessageRepository](http://imgur.com/WTBebN3,oP7TyLe#1)

Comment: Yes, you should add it to your `MessageRepository` ctor.
DON'T use DbSet<T>! Change it to IDbSet<T>.
In order to return in-memory data you have two options
1) use some mocking framework like Moq or NSubstitute
2) create your own InMemoryMessageContext implemetation of IMessageContext interface and InMemoryDbSet<T> implementation of IDbSet<T> interface. Setup everything together and fill InMemoryDbSet<T> with data.

Comment: I've changed to IDbSet in my `IMessageContext` and filled the set. Used [FakeDbSet](http://imgur.com/sufQt1o/). 

But I'm having some problem adding my IMessageRepository to the MessageRepository ctor. I did it like this : http://imgur.com/Q6xb5ag , but after that I had some problems because I got `MessageRepository` in my `CustomerService` ctor, which now need 2 arguments `MessageContext` and `IMessageContext`. I can't add `IMessageContext` as an argument because it is an interface.

I think I'm doing something wrong when I'm adding `IMessageContext` to `MessageRepository` ctor.

Comment: You need to make `public class MessageContext : IMessageContext` and remove `MessageContext context` from your `MessageRepository` ctor parameters. Leave just interface there. And pass `new MessageContext()` in real code and mock in unit test.

Comment: I’ve `public class MessageContext : DbContext, IMessageContext` not `public class MessageContext : IMessageContext`. Is this a problem? I can’t switch them around to `public class MessageContext : IMessageContext, DbContext` because then [I get erro]( http://imgur.com/fB8mnYz). 
I've removed `MessageContext` context from my `MessageRepository` ctor parameters. I’m passing new `MessageContext` in real code: `_messageRepository = new MessageRepository(messageContext);` in the `UserService` ctor for example.

Comment: But in the beginning of the `MessageRepository` class im still declaring  `private MessageContext context;` and using that context for as context in my methods, for example: (`context.SaveChanges()`). Should I instead be using my `IMessageContext` which is in my constructor now? I’ve tried this and I get “Error 'ChatProj.DAL.IMessageContext' does not contain a definition for 'SaveChanges… As far as I don’t have a definition for SaveChanges in MessageContext, but I’ve got public class MessageContext : DbContext, IMessageContext  (mind DbContext) instead of just public interface IMessageContext

Comment: I also get another error in `MessageContext` aswell: http://imgur.com/qzHRzf7 . Big thanks for help this far!

Comment: You should add SaveChanges method to your IMessageContext (and also all other properties\methods of MessageContext that you are using in controller) and declare `private IMessageContext context`. You should also change `DbSet<Message>` into `IDbSet<Message>` in your `MessageContext` class.

Comment: How do I add `SaveChanges` to my `IMessageContext`? Tried [this](http://imgur.com/dHUAd2l) but didn't work. Checked around on google and alot of other SO posts but couldnt find a solution.

Comment: Just add `int SaveChanges();` in your `IMessageContext` definition. That's all. Since `DbContext` already implements this method you have not to change anything else;

Comment: I don't think that `IMessageContext` implements `DbContext`, which means that when `SaveChanges()` in `IMessageContext` get called it doesn't go to the implemented method in `DbContext`. Here is comparison between old context and new: [Picture](http://imgur.com/anBKwGO) . I can't add DbContext to IMessageContext because it is an interface.

Comment: How should I make `SaveChanges` actully call the `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` version of `SaveChanges()` ?

Comment: You are on the right way. Just add `IMessageContext` to your `MessageContext` like `public class MessageContext : DbContext, IMessageContext`. And everything will be fine :).

Comment: Sweet :). `MessageContext` [got a bit upset now](http://imgur.com/WAVNsCC). It wants me to implement the `IMessageContext` methods there, should I? I'm already implementing the methods in `MessageRepository`.

Comment: Yes, you should. Your `MessageRepository` implements `IMessageContext`? It shouldn't.

Comment: Ok, should I implement it [like this?](http://imgur.com/GXhNEOv,fZNrzOQ) My `MessageRepository` looks [like this](http://imgur.com/GXhNEOv,fZNrzOQ#1), it's implementing the `IMessageContext` methods (`GetMessages`, `GetNumMessages`, `CountMessagesByTimeSec`), but it doesn't have `IMessageContext` in its name if that's what you mean. If this is how I'm supposed to implement the `IMessageContext`, then I'll have to add `HubCallerContext` and `Context` to `MessageContext` ctor, should I do that?

Comment: `MessageRepository` looks good. `MessageContext` - change `context` to `this` where errors are highlighted in Studio and remove `CountMessagesByTimeSec` from your `MessageContext`. it should be in repository. Pass `HubCallerContext` to `MessageRepository` ctor.

Comment: Ok, I've changed it around to [something like this](http://imgur.com/fvoLIDe). Though it seems like I have to keep `CountMessagesByTime` in `MessageContext` for it to work like you can see in the right part of the picture.

Comment: I have 3 problems which I think are related. [I'll show them in this link](http://imgur.com/osFnohn). I feel like I should I create my contexts in diffrent ways?

Comment: Show where are you instantiating your repository.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41270/discussion-between-alexk-and-jazzmaster)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these two lines:

```
UserService userService = new UserService();

//Act
userService.SaveMessage(message);
```

You're creating a `userService` instance, and then immediately saving your message.  Now jump into the `SaveMessage` code.

```
public void SaveMessage(Message message)
{
     messageContext.Messages.Add(message);
    _messageRepository.Save();
}
```

Ok, now you're adding stuff to `messageContext`, and then calling `_messageRepository.Save()`.  But where are `messageContext` and `_messageRepository` instantiated?

```
public MessageContext messageContext = new MessageContext();

public UserService()
{
    _messageRepository = new MessageRepository(messageContext);
}
```

You're creating them at instantiation.  The mocks that you've created in your test aren't being used.  Instead of creating instances of these objects in the constructor, you might consider passing them into the `UserService` constructor as arguments.  Then, you can pass in mocked instances in your test.